# VSCode Python extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I having a following problem after install virtualenv on my laptop. Each time I open python file on VSCode it alway show multiple dialog as following. After clicking "OK" many time it back to usual but it is very annoying each time I restart VScode.

I have try:

- Disable Python Extension in VScode: It stop showing each time I restart but Python Extension is my favorite Extension :(
- Change setting in Python Extension back to default: Not working.
- Re - install VScode: Not working

If anyone having similar problem, please help me. Thanks a lot

[image: VScode Python extension problem]

Comment: Try reading through [this](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/15). Comment back if you need help! I'm online for a bit.

Comment: I tried both python -m venv and virtualenv, but I still don't understand why it would affect my vscode, and the problem still the same.

Comment: ok fixed, I have removed anaconda and everything work again :)

Comment: Great! Hopefully I helped!